# How to Use ST_MakeLine query in leaflet to connect to Carto

Tags: postgis, leaflet, carto, query, st-makeline

I want to run in leaflet a query that works in carto Builder to connect points in a line:
[image]

```
SELECT ST_MakeLine(the_geom_webmercator) as the_geom_webmercator, min(cartodb_id) as cartodb_id FROM my_table
```

i try to reproduce this in an html page :
https://jsfiddle.net/2w4a3f1x/

```
var sqlQuery = "SELECT ST_MakeLine(the_geom_webmercator) as the_geom_webmercator, min(cartodb_id) as cartodb_id FROM my_table";

// Set CartoDB Username
var cartoDBUserName = "admin";

// Get CartoDB selection as GeoJSON and Add to Map
function showAll(){
  if(map.hasLayer(pointsincartodb)){
    map.removeLayer(pointsincartodb);
  };
  map.setView(new L.LatLng(40.8722012,14.3036309), 10);
  $.getJSON("https://spatial.query.city/user/"+cartoDBUserName+"/api/v2/sql?format=GeoJSON&q="+sqlQuery, function(data) {
    pointsincartodb = L.geoJson(data,{
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
       layer.bindPopup('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(feature.properties,null,' ').replace(/[\{\}"]/g,'')+'< /pre>');
       layer.cartodb_id=feature.properties.cartodb_id;
      }
    }).addTo(map);
```

But the link to geojson:

gives an error: {"error":["column \"the_geom\" does not exist"]} but i know that the_geom exist!
as you can see here: https://spatial.query.city/user/admin/dataset/my_table

Answer (score 3):

Firstly GeoJSON API expects that the `geometry` part of the GeoJSON data will come from the column called `the_geom`.

Secondly Leaflet expects the `geometry` to be in WGS84 coordinates, unless specifically specified to be different.

To address the above points you need to use `the_geom` column as input to `ST_MakeLine` (since it’s in WGS84), aliasing it to `the_geom`

Based on this change your query to

```js
var sqlQuery = `SELECT ST_MakeLine(the_geom) as the_geom, 
  min(cartodb_id) as cartodb_id FROM my_table`;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sabman/jxLt5n6z/3/

Comment: Can you explain your answer? When explained, answer has much greater value for others with similar problems.

Comment: @TomazicM good point. Done :)